# Converting language to context-free grammar

Tags: computation-theory, computation

{a^m b^ n: m + 1 ≤ n}
I have to generate a context-free language from the above language but I do not know how to do it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the complete definition of the language is {a^m b^ n: m + 1 ≤ n, m≤0}.

The grammar with the rule set:

S -> Xb, X -> Xb, X -> \lambda, X -> aYb, Y -> aYb, Y -> \lambda

and the corresponding sets of terminals and non-terminals with S as the start symbol generates the above language.